# Invalid file: android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/build.xml

Tags: android, ant, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create an Android application only from the command line, build with `ant`
I've made these steps:

1. downloading the appcompat v7 and v4
2. I've run `android update project --target 1 --path . --library ../../Downloads/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`

Now when I run the command `ant debug` I get the following error message:

```
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] Ordered libraries:
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...

BUILD FAILED
/home/xxxx/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:601: Invalid file: /home/xxxx/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/build.xml
```

I've tested also with this [project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/AppCompat)

Using that, I got exactly the same error, and indeed the file "build.xml" is not present in that directory.

I'm specifically looking for command line answers as the goal is to understand "the magic". Does the problem come from me, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

actually it is "normal" that the build.xml is missing, and you have to regenerate it yourself, for this you first go in `android-sdk-linux/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat` directory and then

`android update project --target 1 -p  .`

replace `1` by your target number

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was wondering how I could do this too.